# Limit equality when deriving the normal distribution from Brownian motion

Tags: calculus, probability, limits

I'm going through some old notes on deriving the normal distribution from Brownian motion, and I have a question about "reparameterizing" a limit.

Let me setup the question. Let $t$ index time and let $N$ be the number of "bombardments" to a particle exhibiting discrete Brownian motion. Then the position of the particle at time $t$ can be shown to be

$$
B_t^{(N)} = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}\left( X_1 + X_2 + \dots + X_{\lfloor Nt \rfloor} \right) \tag{1}
$$

where $\sigma^2$ is the mean squared displacement of the particle. We'd like to derive the distribution of the continuous time process, $\{ B_t \}$,

$$
B_t = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} B_t^{(N)}. \tag{2}
$$

To do this, we'll compute the density function

$$
f(x) = \lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0} \frac{\mathbb{P}(B_t \in [x, x+\delta])}{\delta}. \tag{3}
$$

Now here is the step I don't entirely follow. We can pick $\delta$ such that $\delta = 2 / \sigma \sqrt{N}$, and we can rewrite the limit as

$$
f(x) = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\mathbb{P}\left(B_t^{(N)} \in \left[x, x+2\sigma / \sqrt{N} \right]\right)}{2 \sigma / \sqrt{N}}. \tag{4}
$$

I understand the argument intuitively. Eq. $3$ should hold for any $\delta$ we'd like, so why not pick a convenient one. Something like:

$$
\lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0} g(x; \delta) = \lim_{\frac{2\sigma}{\sqrt{N}} \rightarrow 0} g(x; \delta) = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} h(x; N) \tag{5}
$$

My question is: does Eq. 3 equal Eq. 4 exactly or is this a high-level argument that is glossing over details/definitions? It's been years since I've taken calculus, and I don't know if my professor's argument was precise or if he was just outlining the proof.